# List of all available Tile Layers for leaflet

Tags: leaflet, vue2leaflet

I can't seem to find this anywhere - there's examples with open street maps, and hints to using mapbox but otherwise I'm wondering what other maps and url's are available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is definitely no such *exhaustive* list of Tile Providers, but there are plenty other resources listing quite a bit of options.

Strangely, it indeed looks like they cannot be found under such an explicitly stated question yet.

Here are a few:

- [R leaflet Language of the map : Can we specify to use English language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638103/r-leaflet-language-of-the-map-can-we-specify-to-use-english-language/38640057?r=SearchResults#38640057)
- [How to use a different tile provider in openlayer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595374/how-to-use-a-different-tile-provider-in-openlayer3?r=SearchResults)
- on GIS Stack Exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184125/alternative-basemaps-for-leaflet/268290
- and of course the official Leaflet plugins page, which has a section for basemap providers: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#basemap-providers

The main reference with very nice live preview is the [leaflet-providers](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) demo page (although you do not need to use that plugin at all in the end):
https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

> An extension to Leaflet that contains configurations for various free<sup>1</sup> tile providers.

And with the [note](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers#what-do-we-mean-by-free) (emphasis mine):

> What do we mean by *free*?
>
> 1 We try to maintain leaflet-providers in such a way that you'll be able to use the layers we include without paying money. **This doesn't mean no limits apply**, you should always check before using these layers for anything serious.

Answer (score 27):

This one gives a lot of examples (taken from above comments gis.stackexchange link) : https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

The must is that you can preview everything.